# mysql trigger with inner join

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables in mysql database that is linked to my issue tracker.
tables are:

```
1.Issues (contains ID, Issue_name & assignee)
2.change_group (contains ID, Issue_id, created_time)
3.change_item  (contains id, group_id,field, old string , new string)
```

when any change occures about my isuues like changing status or assignee of issue,
table change_group will have new record. one goupid is matched with one or more records in change_item table. for example on group_id can save change in status and assignee of an issue:
now 
according to changing assignees of issue I added a column with assignee name into issue table and I want to have a trigger that save snapshot of assigee field when a change happens.and I tried this:

```
create TRIGGER save_Assignee AFTER INSERT ON changeitem
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
SET new.assignee=(select assignee from jiraissue INNER JOIN changegroup ON jiraissue.ID=changegroup.issueid)
END
```

It seems that I cant Have inner join with trigger at same time.

If anyone has any thoughts on this it would be much appreciated. Thanks

MINA

Comment: Perhaps the issue may not be the inner join so much as how it is referencing the tables whose triggers brought you to this trigger?

Comment: I think you need to update your question with sample data and desired results.  It is very hard to figure out what you want to do based on your text description, and basically impossible from the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

table "issues"

### id     |  Issue_name   | Assignee

11      | R&D           | User1

table "changegroup"

### id     | issue_ID    | Created_time

12    | 11           | 2015/2/2  16:40

table "change_item"

### id    |  group_id    | field   | old string   | new string

### 13    | 12           |status   | to do        | in progress

I want to have a trigger to save who is assignee at the time that change happens on an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You want a *before* insert trigger, not an *after* insert trigger:

```
create TRIGGER save_Assignee BEFORE INSERT ON changeitem
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
SET new.assignee=(select assignee from jiraissue INNER JOIN changegroup ON jiraissue.ID = changegroup.issueid)
END
```

I also suspect that your subquery is all wrong.  It probably returns too many rows, because it needs a reference to `new`.  However, that is not your question.  If you decide that you have such problems, then ask another question, with sample data and desired results.